# how to Set default ringtone with a ringtone from server

Tags: android, ringtone

I am trying to set default ringtone by using a ringtone from my server. So, first I tried to download my ringtone from url to sd card with this code :

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myfoldername/dir3");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, myringtonename + ".mp3");
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

but the ringtone will save in phone storage not SD card.
after that, i try to set ringtone from sd card with this code :

```
private void setrington() {
            String path = getFilesDir()+"/sdcard/myfoldername/dir3/";
            File k = new File(path, myringtonename + ".mp3"); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = Etelaat.this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);

        }
```

setting ringtone codes are not working and i see this notes in logcat :

```
05-19 01:26:23.841: V/Provider/Settings(3485):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
05-19 01:26:23.848: D/ActivityThread(3485): hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@42ce86c0,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@42ce9098
05-19 01:26:23.979: D/Provider/Settings(3485): put string name = ringtone , value = content://media/internal/audio/media/142 userHandle = 0
05-19 01:26:24.031: I/RingtoneManager(3485): Set actual default ringtone uri= content://media/internal/audio/media/142
```

also I tried this :

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myfoldername/dir3");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, myringtonename + ".mp3");
```

Even, it's not working :

```
05-19 01:36:22.478: V/Provider/Settings(7367):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
05-19 01:36:22.494: D/ActivityThread(7367): hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@42cce4c8,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@42cceea0
05-19 01:36:22.606: D/Provider/Settings(7367): put string name = ringtone , value = null userHandle = 0
05-19 01:36:22.631: I/RingtoneManager(7367): Set actual default ringtone uri= null
```

Comment: instead of sd card use external storage. I have nexus 4 and it doesnt have sd card so when i used external storage it works perfectly fine.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal